# couchdb futon document editor - can I customize the indentation rules?

Tags: couchdb, customization, couchdb-futon

Suppose that I want to customize the indentation rules of the foton document editor, where and how can I do that?

I'll elaborate.

The foton editor lays out document like this:
 (which to my flavor is completely annoying)

```
{
   "_id": "1326017821636",
   "_rev": "2-51ab614953437181a24f1c073fbc6201",
   "doc_type": 0,
   "step": 2,
   "data": {
       "map1": {
           "attr1": 73031,
           "attr2": "strval"
       },
       "map2": {
           "att1": 52001,
           "att2": "strval"
       },
       "mapmap": {
           "map": {
               "id11": {
                   "id": "id11",
                   "attr": "attr",
                   "attr2": 2222
               },
               "id1211": {
                   "id": "id1211",
                   "attr": "attr",
                   "attr2": 2222
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

And what would I want to change, you may ask? It seems pritty standard.
Well, I'm not a standard person. To my observations many standards evolved arbitrarily and suffer lack of thought. Besides, if I was a standard-follower I was not asking about customization ;)

Shortly - 
 - 3 spaces tab indent. Why 3? not 2 and not 4. just 3? LOL
 - block formation - opening a block draws down a line in the worng place
 - commas are in the wrong side

So I want it to be like this:
(and I even have the JS code that does it, I just need help in **where to put it**)

```
{ "_id"      : "1326017821636"
, "_rev"     : "2-51ab614953437181a24f1c073fbc6201"
, "doc_type" : 0
, "step"     : 2
, "data"     : 
    { "map1" : 
        { "attr1" : 73031
        , "attr2" : "strval"
        }
    , "map2" :
        { "att1" : 52001
        , "att2" : "strval"
        }
    , "mapmap" : 
        { "map" : 
            { "id11"   : 
                 { "id"    : "id11"
                 , "attr"  : "attr"
                 , "attr2" : 2222
                 }
            }
        ,   { "id1122" : 
                 { "id"    : "id11"
                 , "attr"  : "attr"
                 , "attr2" : 2222
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why I do it this way?
- it looks more tabular. All syntax scuffold of same object/array are in the same column
  (who placed the comma in the wrong side of the statement anyway)
- no redunand wasted empty lines
- only the start-block is an edge case (opposed to in the other way you have a case for begining a block and a case for ending a block and a case for every line).

It would have been fine if I could perform my indentations and the foton will not ruin them everytime it validates the document. But, since it does, I need to get into this mechanism and replace it's indentor with one of my own.

Any directions?

P.S:
If you know the answer here - you might know the answer to this question:
[couchdb futon document editor - can I customize the document validation part?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786987/couchdb-futon-document-editor-can-i-customize-the-document-validation-rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, after a quick browse, this is where you might want to look:

https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/share/www/script/futon.browse.js#L899

You will have a corresponding /share/www/script folder on your local couchdb instance if you want to play around editing it live.