# couchdb futon document editor - can I customize the document validation part?

Tags: couchdb, customization, couchdb-futon

A **VERY** nice to have would be if I could edit object-literals in this editor's text-field instead of JSON expressions.

If I could replace the JSON parse with a simple `eval` - it will make editing sooooo much easier! (and help me design document structures for my projects soooo much more easily)

I mean, gosh!! it's not a protocol school, it's an editor's tool. 
The goal of the tool is not to teach me the protocol and comment me on every petty mistake, but to help me design documents for the software.
Why must it ensist on strict JSON? Can't it live with Object Literals, and do for us the
 `JSON.stringify( eval(editor_textarea.value))`
woulnd't that be cool? LOL :D
(yea yea, catching errors and feeding back to the user)

(and for who ever missed the difference  - it is mainly in the quote marks in attribute names. 
the dry strict JSON protocol require quotemarks ALWAYS, no question asked, where JS object literal require quote-marks only for attribute names that are not legal JS variable names and accepts also numbers without quotation marks)

Strict dry JSON:

```
{ "attribute" : "value"
, "mapmap"    : 
    { "map" :
        { "attr" : "sdss" 
        , "123"  : "ss32332"
        , "val"  : 23323
        , "456"  : "ss32332"
        }  
    }
 }
```

Object Literal

```
{ attribute: "value"
, mapmap   :
    { map :
        { attr : "sdss"
        , 123  : "ss32332"
        , val  : 23323
        , 456  : "ss32332"
        }
    }
}
```

Well, it won't solve me missing commas or mismatching brakets, but it does make life easier, where quote marks are a big part of the scaffold.

If you can point me to where I can change this even as patch on the futon I'll be soooOOO greatful :)

Maybe later we can integrate there an editor helper such as the cool one in github source-editor or the one in jsfiddle, that helps you indent and color things nicely.
But lets start with a simple eval. 
it will make life easier... :)

It can also let me generate complicated documents using JS code without any additional test software...

Happy coding :)

P.S
If you know the answer here - you might know the answer to this question:
[couchdb futon document editor - can I customize the indentation rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786845/couchdb-futon-document-editor-can-i-customize-the-indentation-rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick browse, and I believe this is where you will want to add your eval:

https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/share/www/script/futon.browse.js#L911

and here:

https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/share/www/script/futon.browse.js#L902

You can edit your local couchdb instance share/www/script/futon.browse.js if you want to see live changes.